# Defining an inline extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Consider the following code:

```
Func<int,bool> hasFullAccess = (mask => mask % 2 == 1);
foreach (AccessControlEntry ace in (IEnumerable)usrAcl)
{
    if (hasFullAccess(ace.AccessMask)
```

How can I tell the Func that it is an extension method, such that I can do

```
    if (ace.AccessMask.hasFullAccess())
```

or is this impossible?

Comment: The fact they must be static in a static class prohibits this.

Comment: Why would you want that? Nothing wrong with your current code, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. You need to declare a separate extension method for that:

```
public static class Extensions 
{
    public static bool HasFullAccess(this int mask)
    { 
        return mask % 2 == 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No ([C# 5.0 specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) §10.6.9 Extension methods); Even if you could, that would also require a change to the name resolution specification (§7.6.5.2 Extension method invocations).

Instead you could try something like this:

```
Func<AccessControlEntry,bool> hasFullAccess = (ace => ace.AccessMask % 2 == 1);

// cast usrAcl as required get IEnumerable<AccessControlEntry>
foreach (var ace in usrAcl.Where(hasFullAccess))
{
}
```